‹‹ Il ne faut pas avoir trop de ›› / ‹‹ Il ne faut pas trop avoir de ››
I have come across both

‹‹ Il ne faut pas avoir trop de scrupules ››

and

‹‹ Il ne faut pas trop avoir de scrupules ››

What is the difference between them, if any, in terms of register, nuance, etc.?

The difference is not very obvious ( I tried to highlight the nuance by exaggerating the difference):

Il ne faut pas avoir trop de scrupules

You may be scrupulous, but not that much.

Il ne faut pas trop avoir de scrupules

Sometimes, you shouldn't be scrupulous.
It is perhaps clearer when comparing :

Il ne faut pas mettre trop d'eau
(Don't put too much water)

and

il ne faut pas trop mettre d'eau
(What may mean Watering is not really recommended)


+1 mais j'ai l'impression, peut-être fausse, que not very evident est un peu un gallicisme ici. Pour moi, en anglais, evident c'est quand il y a une preuve de quelque chose. J'aurais mis not obvious.

@jlliagre even if evident and obvious are synonyms, obvious is more appropriate.

La différence est pas trop évidente? How could you possibly suspect a gallicism here, is what I wonder.

@FrançoisJurain On traduit evident et obvious par 'évident', mais ils n'ont pas
tout à fait le même sens.

@jlliagre à croire que l'obviosité est pas trop dans l'oeil du spectateur.

@FrançoisJurain Je ne comprends pas pourquoi tu mets pas trop en gras deux fois, ni pourquoi tu ne comprends pas pourquoi je suspectais un gallicisme d'ailleurs.

@jlliagre c'était de l'incompréhension feinte et narquoise.

Il ne faut pas mettre trop d'eau. cannot be: Don't put too much water. Idiomatic would be: Don't put too much water in/on something OR Don't use too much water. [to do something]

@FrançoisJurain Je n'avais pas compris l'incompréhension, comprenne qui pourra !

Un petit commentaire aussi pour dire que pas trop avoir est dans un registre un tout petit peu plus soutenu à mon avis, et aussi peut-être d'usage un peu moins fréquent (?)

@Frank Donc, les deux veulent dire la même chose? J'avais pensé ça aussi...

@Lambie Non pas tout à fait, il y a bien une différence de sens.

@Frank Quel est donc la différence de sens? Si "pas trop avoir" est dans un registre un "tout petit peu plus soutenu", qu'est-ce l'expression de base? Si on dit, que, p.ex. "Je voudrais vous poser la question etc" est plus soutenu (voire poli) que: Je veux vous poser une question, l'un se réfère à l'autre, n'est-ce pas?

@Lambie As per Graffito's.

Literally,  "n'avoir pas trop de scrupules" means that "scrupules" should not be adhered to in a number that is too great, whereas "ne pas trop avoir de scrupules" means "to possess "scrupules', but that this possession should not be to a too high degree", which is rather nonsensical and corresponds to the fact that this is not found in the books.

Similarly, you will find "ne pas avoir trop d'argent" but not "ne pas trop avoir d'argent", or, at least this latter form is going to be rarely met with on the page.

It probably means that the interpretation given above (illogical) is usually that felt by most speakers of the language ; therefore  it is better to avoid it and consider its rare occurrences as French that is not quite as good.
Here is another ngram that will contribute to driving this idea home.

